# Why doesn't jupyter notebook use fullscreen for output

Tags: jupyter-notebook

[cant post images yet as this is my first question so here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZ6Cr.png)

Why cant my output use full screen. It only uses half a screen
Is there any way to change this?

Comment: Post some examples in the question post so that we can at least try to understand what your issue is.

Comment: The link is an example. Cant post images yet